# How to remove specific characters string in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Let's say i have a string $msg below:

```
$msg = '$hello , ken (JX02), Your Orders $invoiceno has been delivered. Thank you.';
```

Then, i will search for the variables that i had defined before, if yes, i will replace from the string.

```
$hello = "morning!";
$msg = str_replace( '$hello' ,$hello,$msg);
```

which will give me :

```
morning! , ken (JX02), Your Orders $invoiceno has been delivered. Thank you.
```

That is fine. But if the variable did not defined, I want to remove it from the string $msg.
Let's say i did not define $invoiceno, then :

```
morning! , ken (JX02), Your Orders has been delivered. Thank you.
```

Since the variables name is not fixed, and inputted by the user dynamically, then how can i achieve this function?

Comment: How do you decide what is a variable name, and what is not? If you're just using a preceding $ to decide, do all your variable substitutions first, then remove any words that start with a dollar sign. You know that if you used double-quotes around the string assignment in your first code block, PHP would do all the variable name / value substitution for you, right?

Comment: I had handled all the variables replacement, the main problem is how to remove any words that start with a dollar sign AND not defined from my program(apply something like isset.. etc..)

Comment: One way would be to `explode` the final string into an array, scan down each element and check for your conditions, and either remove the words from the array and use `implode` at the end, or just build the string as you loop through. In fact, you could do that for the whole operation.

Comment: Quick note: if `$hello` is not set, you'll still have that comma at the start. If `$invoiceno` is not set and you print that string on console, it will leave you with two spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution. First, replace all variables that i had set.

Then, Find out each words that start with a dollar sign, then explode it, then remove the first string of each element of the array. Last, combine them back into a string.

```
    $new_msg = explode("$",$new_msg);
    $str = '';
    if(count($new_msg) > 0){
        foreach($new_msg as $k => $m){
            if($k > 0){
                $new_msg[$k] = substr(strstr($new_msg[$k]," "), 1);
            }

            $str .= $new_msg[$k];
        }
    }

    $new_msg = $str;
```

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, but if it gives you the required result, that's great. I'd have exploded by a space, then loop through each word, if it starts with a `$` then either put in the variable value (if it exists) or nothing (if it does not), and append it back to your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double-quoted strings to auto-insert a variable's contents into a string.

```
$hello = 'Testname';
$msg = "$hello - your order is ready!";
echo $msg;
```

Output:

```
Testname - your order is ready!
```

You can also use more complicated variables such as those with an index by adding {} around it.

```
$customer['first_name'] = 'Tester';
$msg = "{$customer['first_name']}, your order is ready!";
echo $msg;
```

Output:

```
Tester, your order is ready!
```

If the variable is undefined, it will throw an E_NOTICE in php and not print anything in its place.

```
$msg = "$undefinedvariable, your order is ready!";
echo $msg;
```

Output:

```
, your order is ready!
```

*Notice: Undefined variable: undefinedvariable in myscript.php on line 1*

Comment: What if i don't define $hello, and do not want $hello display in my $msg?

Comment: What happens if you try that in a short bit of code? What do you get? (I can't remember, I think it will just leave the unsubstituted names in the string, but I don't know without trying it.)

Comment: @droopsnoot Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: invoiceno

Comment: Added some clarifications

Comment: OK, well if you get an error, that tells you that you can't just do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know this is the best way or not? but you can do this way,

```
<?php
$msg = '$hello , ken (JX02), Your Orders $invoiceno has been delivered. Thank you.';
$hello = "morning!";
$msg = isset($hello) ? str_replace( '$hello' , $hello, $msg): str_replace( '$hello' , "", $msg);
$msg = isset($invoiceno) ? str_replace( '$invoiceno' , $invoiceno, $msg): str_replace( '$invoiceno' , "", $msg);
echo str_replace("  ", " ", $msg);;
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GL5RO

Comment: The problem here is that it only works if you know all the variable names. The OP said that they don't.

Comment: I can fix the script to make it dynamic variable or use array for consumer but I did it Static to make it easier for OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get all variable names to array, fill it with value or nothing and replace by strtr function

```
$hello = "morning!";
$msg = '$hello , ken (JX02), Your Orders $invoiceno has been delivered. Thank you.';

preg_match_all('/\$(\w+)/', $msg, $m);

$keys = array_fill_keys($m[1], '');

foreach($keys as $k=>&$v) {
    if(isset($$k)) $v = $$k;
}

echo strtr($msg, $keys);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df3e3f5d711957f02335aa2358baddac90f92a40)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for template strings, I would use something like `{{ variable }}` vs `$` as any forgetting `'` over `"` will cause issues/confusion, you can then use a simple string like:

`'{{ hello }}, ken (JX02), Your Orders {{ invoiceno }} has been delivered. Thank you.'`

and a regex like `/{{[ ]{0,}([\w\_-]{1,})[ ]{0,}}}/` to match whats between the placeholders, then select/set from a set of replacements.

To incorporate that idea into using `$`, one could do the following which will parse out the variables, replace (from replacments array or local variables (previously set):

```
<?php
$hello = 'Hi'; // gets replaced (in $replacements)
$name = 'ken'; // gets replaced (in $GLOBALS)

//  
$replacements = [
  'hello' => 'morning',
  'invoiceno' => 1234
];

$msg = '$hello, $name (JX02), Your Orders $invoiceno has been delivered. $test $123,99 $123.99 Thank you.';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\$([\w\_-]{1,})/', function ($match) use ($replacements) {
    return array_key_exists($match[1], $replacements) ? $replacements[$match[1]] : (
      isset($GLOBALS[$match[1]]) ? $GLOBALS[$match[1]] : '$'.$match[1]
    );
}, $msg);

echo $result; // morning, ken (JX02), Your Orders 1234 has been delivered. $test $123,99 $123.99 Thank you.
```

**Working example:**

https://3v4l.org/UMs9h